# Prove that a set is open on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on an open subset ${\cal S}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Prove that the set $\{ (x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n, y) : x \in {\cal S}, y>f(x) \}$ is an open subset on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

It would be useful to abbreviate the set $(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n, y) = ({\bf x}, {\bf y})$.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to write the set {(x,y)} as the inverse of S, because then f-1(S) would be open.

Comment: @SeanRoberson any suggestions please?

Comment: Your set is not $f^{-1}(S)$, so you give up that idea. Try showing that if $({\mathbf x}. {\mathbf y})$ is in the set, then so is any $({\mathbf x'}. {\mathbf y'})$ sufficiently close to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try what Paul wrote. Another option is to show that the complement is closed (either with or without the limit point characterization).

Yet another approach, which is more in line with your own attempt is to define a function $\mu: \mathcal S \times \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\mu(\boldsymbol{x}, y) := f(\boldsymbol x)-y$. This function is continuous, and $(0, \infty) \subset \mathbb R$ is open. You may then express your given set as
$$
\{(\boldsymbol x, y) \mid f(\boldsymbol x)-y > 0\} = \mu^{-1}((0,\infty))\, .
$$
which is open, by the definition of continuity of $\mu$.

Comment: The function $\mu$ should be defined on $\mathcal{S} \times \mathbb{R}$ and I think that $\mu^{-1}\big( ]0,+\infty[ \big)$ is:

$$ \lbrace (x,y) \in S \times \mathbb{R}, \; y - f(x) \color{red}{>} 0 \rbrace $$

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks. Fixed the typos.